# Parse json data in golang

Tags: json, go

I am trying to print out a json value that I am getting from a public API.

my json response:

```
[
    {
        "address": "0x6679eb24f59dfe111864aec72b443d1da666b360",
        "name": "ARIVA",
        "symbol": "ARV",
        "logo": null,
        "logo_hash": null,
        "thumbnail": null,
        "decimals": "8",
        "block_number": "8242108",
        "validated": 1
    }
]
```

the code:

```
        type TokenNamingInfo struct {
            TokenName    string `json:"name"`
            TokenAddress string `json:"address"`
            TokenSymbol  string `json:"symbol"`
        }

        reqmeta, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://somesite.com", nil)
        if err != nil {
            // handle err
        }
        reqmeta.Header.Set("Accept", "application/json")
        reqmeta.Header.Set("X-Api-Key", "api")

        respmeta, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(reqmeta)
        if err != nil {
            // handle err
        }
        defer respmeta.Body.Close()

        var responseTokenSymbol TokenNamingInfo
        json.Unmarshal(tokensymbol, &responseTokenPrice)
```

However, this is not working and does not print.

```
        fmt.Println(responseTokenSymbol.name)
```

this is working if my json and struct looks like the below, with the same above procedure.

```
{
    "nativePrice": {
        "value": "1906303859440",
        "decimals": 18,
        "name": "Binance Coin",
        "symbol": "BNB"
    },
    "usdPrice": 0.000875604424294528,
    "exchangeAddress": "0xcA143Ce32Fe78f1f7019d7d551a6402fC5350c73",
    "exchangeName": "PancakeSwap v2"
}

        type TokenPriceInfo struct {
            Price           float64 `json:"usdPrice"`
            ExchangeName    string  `json:"exchangeName"`
            ExchangeAddress string  `json:"exchangeAddress"`
        }
```

Comment: You need to unmarshal into a slice since the json is an array with a single object in it `[ { ... } ]`.

Comment: The amount of random, incorrect variable names in the code snippet is remarkable though. But who gives a f*, right?

Comment: well am just playing around not really a clean code. how can I unmarshal it into a slice ?

Comment: Well that makes it more troublesome, for anyone who wants to help, to suggest a solution. Anyway, to unmarshal into a slice of structs you'd do this:  `var slice []Struct`; `json.Unmarshal(data, &slice)`; `fmt.Println(slice[0].Field)`.

Comment: well that solved it :) thank you

Comment: The error retuned from json.Unmarshal describes the problem.  Always handle errors.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like that:

```js
import (
"io/ioutil"
"net/http"
"fmt"
"encoding/json"
)

type TokenNamingInfo struct {
    TokenName    string `json:"name"`
    TokenAddress string `json:"address"`
    TokenSymbol  string `json:"symbol"`
    Logo  string `json:"logo"`
    LogoHash  string `json:"logo_hash"`
    Thumbnail  string `json:"thumbnail"`
    Decimals  int `json:"decimals"`
    BlockNumber  string `json:"block_number"`
    Validated  string `json:"validated"`
}

reqmeta, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://somesite.com", nil)

if err != nil {
    // handle err
}

reqmeta.Header.Set("Accept", "application/json")
reqmeta.Header.Set("X-Api-Key", "api")

respmeta, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(reqmeta)
if err != nil {
    // handle err
}
defer respmeta.Body.Close()
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(respmeta.Body)

if err != nil {
// handle err
}
fmt.Println(string(body)) // Print result

responseTokenSymbol := &TokenNamingInfo{}

err = json.Unmarshal(body, responseTokenSymbol)
if err != nil {
 // handle error
}
fmt.Println(responseTokenSymbol.TokenName) // Print name
```